# Difficulties with constructing path to desired element?, Excel VBA

Tags: html, vba

I'm new to VBA, trying to learn it. Facing a minor problem in extracting one data point from html.
Below is the html

{  div class="category">**Category:** Shopping

I just want to extract ( **Shopping** ) from this but what I'm getting is (**Category:Shopping**).

I'm using this code

```
html.querySelector(".category").innerText
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the simplest is to use Replace$

```
data = Replace$(html.querySelector(".category").innerText,"Category:", vbNullString)
```

You could possibly use split

```
data = Trim$(Split(html.querySelector(".category").innerText,"Category:")(1))
```